# Should this happen with expected values? [regressions in matrix form]

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, expected-value

I have the functional form y= β + ε I'm trying to calculate Var(ε|X) and know that Var(ε|X) = E(εε'|X) as usual. But in calculating E(εε'|X), there's a problem I keep running into.

Here's what I did: E(εε'|X)= E(yy'-yβ'-βy'+ββ'|X)

(then expand out the y's)

= E(ββ'+εβ'+ βε'+ εε' + ....|X)

= E(ββ'|X) + E(εβ'|X) + E(βε'|X)+ E(εε'|X) + E(....|X)

But then, you see that I end up with E(εε'|X) within the solution of E(εε'|X) and that shouldn't happen. That can't be possible, right?

Everything else seems correct, what might be the problem?

Comment: I assume you mean the form y=beta'*X+eps.You should not expand the y's as the y's come already from an expansion. But I can't really help you if I don't know where you are heading with the calculation. You want the conditional variance of the epsilon in a certain manner? Otherwise E(eps*eps'|X) is completely fine as you can replace theoretical moments by empirical moments and use the eps which you can back out of your regression.

Comment: Add: you can replace the epsilon by y-beta'X as you did and then drag out the X's (as they are known) and the beta's (as they are supposevly constant).

Comment: No, just y=beta+epsilon. There's no x in the formula but the professor said that the beta is equal to the population mean, mu. I don't know what the end is supposed to look like since it's just a practice exercise

Comment: @J3lackkyy When I leave y, I just get E(yy'|X)-betabeta'. I can't remove the y''s because they depend on X but I also don't know that the expectation should remain

Comment: As your model is y=beta+epsilon, I am already confused that you want to calculate the conditional variance with respect to X? Could you give me more context, maybe the full exercise description?

Comment: Further, having expectations left is no problem. In practice, you would simply replace expectations with sample means and estimate it that way

Comment: Thank you! Here's the description: The model specification is  yi = beta + epsi, (hint: beta=mu). E(εi|xi)=0. cov(εi,εj|xi,xj)=0 for i ̸= j and Var(εi|xi) = σ2x2i , with xi > 0. Find Var(ε|X) = E(εε′|X) @J3lackkyy